# Java encoding breaks between Mac and some Linux boxes

Tags: java, encoding, mime

I have this problem where on my local development machine, and on one AWS Linux box, UTF-8 strings are properly encoded, but on another machine they are being replaced with question marks. The strings originate in MIME emails and both originate in a common code path. The difference between the proper encoding and the question marks appears both in stderr and in a file on AWS S3 we are uploading to. I have run locally both in IntelliJ and *using the exact same jar that is deployed to the broken Linux box.*

On all machines the version of Java is the same:

> java version "1.7.0_04"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)

I used the following program to verify that the default charset is the same everywhere:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());    
    }
}
```

And all boxes show

> UTF-8

All MIME strings we save in memory as bytes before returning to higher level code as a UTF-8 encoded String, via this code:

```
static final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
// ...
return new String(bytes, ImapClient.charset);
```

It is then turned into an `InputStream` via `InputStream mimeStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(mime)` and parsed via `org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeTokenStream`.

When we get to the subject field, which is the one that is failing to properly encode, we use

```
public static String decodeBodyText(String str) {
    try {
        return MimeUtility.decodeText(str);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exc) {
        // ignore
    }
    return str;
}
```

`MimeUtility` is from `javax.mail.internet` package.

This is the subject that is then showing up differently in a `System.err.println` call.

What causes this improper encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Was missing `-Dmail.mime.charset=utf-8`. That defaulted differently on different machines for some reason but this fixed it.